# how to connect nox with android studio on macbook

Tags: android

how to connect nox with android studio on macbook
I have tried the usual way in use on windows therapy can not, by using this code on the terminal nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001.

Comment: Is this about programming? It would be useful to see some code. Please verify this link on how to ask questions in Stack Overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It will help the community to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on NOX terminal to connect to adb react native debugging:

```
adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001
```